# Implementing schedulable states in corda

Tags: corda

How do we implement schedulable state in corda? In my case i need to issue a monthly statement, so can schedulablestate be used for this?

Comment: That's an interesting question, I'm working on a similar use case but I'm not at the practical implementation yet, however yes, schedulableState is what you need

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of things you need to do.

Firstly, your state object needs to implement the `SchedulableState` interface. It adds an additional method:

```
interface SchedulableState : ContractState {
    /**
     * Indicate whether there is some activity to be performed at some future point in time with respect to this
     * [ContractState], what that activity is and at what point in time it should be initiated.
     * This can be used to implement deadlines for payment or processing of financial instruments according to a schedule.
     *
     * The state has no reference to it's own StateRef, so supply that for use as input to any FlowLogic constructed.
     *
     * @return null if there is no activity to schedule.
     */
    fun nextScheduledActivity(thisStateRef: StateRef, flowLogicRefFactory: FlowLogicRefFactory): ScheduledActivity?
}
```

This interface requires a method named `nextScheduledActivity` to be implemented which returns an optional `ScheduledActivity` instance. `ScheduledActivity` captures what `FlowLogic` instance each node will run, to perform the activity, and when it will run is described by a `java.time.Instant`. Once your state implements this interface and is tracked by the vault, it can expect to be queried for the next activity when committed to the vault. Example:

```
class ExampleState(val initiator: Party,
                   val requestTime: Instant,
                   val delay: Long) : SchedulableState {
     override val contract: Contract get() = DUMMY_PROGRAM_ID
     override val participants: List<AbstractParty> get() = listOf(initiator)
     override fun nextScheduledActivity(thisStateRef: StateRef, flowLogicRefFactory: FlowLogicRefFactory): ScheduledActivity? {
         val responseTime = requestTime.plusSeconds(delay)
         val flowRef = flowLogicRefFactory.create(FlowToStart::class.java)
         return ScheduledActivity(flowRef, responseTime)
     }
 }
```

Secondly, the `FlowLogic` class which is schedulted to start (in this case `FlowToStart`) must be also annotated with `@SchedulableFlow.` E.g.

```
@InitiatingFlow
@SchedulableFlow
class FlowToStart : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        // Do stuff.
    }
}
```

Now, when `ExampleState` is stored in the vault, the `FlowToStart` will be schedulted to start at the offset time specified in the `ExampleState`.

That's it!

Comment: In my case i need to create monthly statements based on the principal amount in a parent state. So, my parent state will be schedulablestate which schedules a flow every month that creates monthly statements(child states). Am i right?

Comment: That's exactly right. You implement schedulable state and make the time delay one month. Then the flow that issues statements will be executed when the timer triggers. Cheers

Comment: schedulable state is part of a tx between 2 nodes and this state resides in both parties' nodes. In such case, the scheduler flow will be triggered in both the nodes. But i want it to be triggered in only one node. is it possible?

Comment: Do we need to add logic for Network Initiation Handler in normal implementation where the same flow logic has to be executed on both sides?