# How to trigger a corda Scedulable flow from one node but to be executed by another node

Tags: corda

I am referring the link [Implementing schedulable states in corda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45712795/implementing-schedulable-states-in-corda)

In My usecase: There are 3 parties, Party A, Party B and Central Party.
Party A will create a deal state with Central Party and same way , Party B will also create a deal state with Central Party.

So now central party will have two deal states.

Whenever a deal state comes into Central Party, it has to check some conditions and then create a trade automatically.Trade flow creation should be triggered from Central party , **but not to be executed by Parties.**

Can i Acheive it through schedulable state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scheduled flow associated with a `SchedulableState` will be executed by every party who is storing the state. So it will be executed by Party A/Party B *and* by Central Party.

You need to put some logic at the start of the scheduled flow to abort if you are not the Central Party. Something like:

```
@InitiatingFlow
@SchedulableFlow
class ScheduledFlow(private val stateRef: StateRef) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
    @Suspendable
    override fun call() {
        if (ourIdentity.name.organisation != "Central Party") {
            return
        }

        // TODO("Further flow logic")
    }
}
```

Comment: When would we prefer to allow all party to run? Wouldnt that cause some kind of racing condition? Or when some cases the flow depends heavily on some send/receive sequence involving some stateRef only owned by one side of the party?